# is it possible to add google tracking code inside in .jsonp file

Tags: jsonp

I use this inside my jsonp file for arrows:
"arrows": {
            "right": {
                "top": 200,
                "right": 0,
                "width": 60,
                "height": 120
            },
            "left": {
                "top": 0,
                "left": 0,
                "width": 0,
                "height": 0
            }
        }
    }

Does anyone know how to add Google tracking on click to each arrow?

This is regular tracking code:
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mypagename', 'click', 'arrow'])

Appreciate any help.

Comment: No, a .json file is for data only. You can't include a script function call inside it.

Comment: Thanks, in this case what would be  the way of  tracking those arrows if I have no html elements html page?

Comment: Can you include your code which loads the data from the json file? Are you using a javascript framework for this? Which one?

Comment: No framework, json file just linked on the page...

Comment: You need to include the code from your page that gets the data from the json file and generates the arrows in html.

Comment: //Next arrow code as an example:
if (data[i].arrows.right){
$next = $("<span>")
       .attr("class", "ef-sl-right")
.css({
        "top": data[i].arrows.right.top,
        "right": data[i].arrows.right.right,
        "width": data[i].arrows.right.width,
        "height": data[i].arrows.right.height
})
       .appendTo($li);
}
     
        "height": data[i].arrows.left.height
})
       .appendTo($li);
}

$li.appendTo($main);
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40669/discussion-between-marb-and-ekoostikmartin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "add Google tracking on click to each arrow". Your data is just data, and not arrows. It's possible your client-side javascript uses the data to display something that's clickable, but that's all a matter of client-side javascript and has nothing to do with JSONP.

It is however technically possible to have the JSONP response itself trigger Google tracking code. It's important to remember that JSONP is basically just a piece of javascript that promises to call a specified callback function with some data. But nothing is stopping you from executing some javascript before that. Instead of the usual JSONP response:

```
callback({"arrows": { "right": { "top": 200, "right": 0, "width": 60, "height": 120 }, "left": { "top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 0, "height": 0 }}}});
```

You could do something like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mypagename', 'click', 'arrow']);
callback({"arrows": { "right": { "top": 200, "right": 0, "width": 60, "height": 120 }, "left": { "top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 0, "height": 0 }}}});
```

That is a Google tracking call inside a JSONP response. But I get the impression you don't actually want it inside the JSONP, you probably want it in your user interface. So put it there.

If you're using jQuery, just do

```
element.click(function() {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mypagename', 'click', 'arrow'])});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it appeared that is much simpler than i thought.